# Someone who praises or thanks others all the time when it is no big deal

Tags: phrase-requests

In the process it dumbs everything down. Real achievement or when it is really deserved becomes ordinary and loses impact.

Comment: You need more context. As it stands, there are probably many words that will work. Also, from the SWR tag:"This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Comment: As both aspects of this type of behaviour are well taken into account in "Common term or single word for someone who is embarrassingly over-complimentary", mentioned in the preceding comment, this question appears to be a sure duplicate.

Comment: "Someone who praises or thanks others all the time when it is no big deal" ... polite

Comment: You seem to be expressing an opinion and asking users to agree with you rather than asking about a word.

Comment: Yes,but this is unfortunate. I thought I would show what the effect would be and it might then help narrow down a suitable word or phrase.

Answer (score 1):

I like the word [obsequious](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/obsequious), in this sense:

> 2. Servilely or meanly attentive; compliant to excess; cringing; fawning; as, obsequious flatterer, parasite.

Answer (score 0):

Such superfluous praise can be referred to as being *Over the Top*.

The polite response that attempts to tamp it down would be; *You are too kind.*